# How to get errors when calling mongoc_collection_find function?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

Looking at the functions used in the [Mongo C driver](http://mongoc.org) to do operations on collections, I see that many of them use a `bson_error_t*` return parameter to get possible errors (and they return `false` in that case).

For instance [mongo_collection_insert](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.3/mongoc_collection_insert.html):

bool

```
mongoc_collection_insert (mongoc_collection_t *collection,
                          mongoc_insert_flags_t flags,
                          const bson_t *document,
                          const mongoc_write_concern_t *write_concern,
                          bson_error_t *error);
```

Others ([mongoc_collection_update](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.3/mongoc_collection_update.html) or [mongoc_collection_remove](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.3/mongoc_collection_remove.html)) work the same way.

However, the function to do queries ([mongoc_collection_find](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.17.3/mongoc_collection_find.html)) has the following signature:

```
mongoc_cursor_t *
mongoc_collection_find (mongoc_collection_t *collection,
                        mongoc_query_flags_t flags,
                        uint32_t skip,
                        uint32_t limit,
                        uint32_t batch_size,
                        const bson_t *query,
                        const bson_t *fields,
                        const mongoc_read_prefs_t *read_prefs)
```

There is not `bson_error_t*` parameter in this case, so how potential errors are returned?

I have thought that maybe checking for return value NULL-ness could mean error (although according to documentation return value is *"A newly allocated mongoc_cursor_t that should be freed with mongoc_cursor_destroy() when no longer in use"* and they don't mention the possibility of being NULL in case of fail) but even in that case, how to know which exact error has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation [mongoc_collection_aggregate](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/mongoc_collection_aggregate.html) is pretty similar to `mongoc_collection_find` and the documentation there says:

> This function returns a newly allocated `mongoc_cursor_t` that should be freed with `mongoc_cursor_destroy()` when no longer in use. The returned `mongoc_cursor_t` is never `NULL`; if the parameters are invalid, the `bson_error_t` in the `mongoc_cursor_t` is filled out, and the `mongoc_cursor_t` is returned before the server is selected. The user must call `mongoc_cursor_next()` on the returned `mongoc_cursor_t` to execute the aggregation pipeline.

So maybe the problem is that `mongoc_collection_find` is incomplete but it works in the same way.

I have proposed a [modification to Mongo C driver documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/pull/740) to confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: Taking into account the positive feedback in the contributed PR to Mongo C driver documentation (see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/pull/740#pullrequestreview-621146602) I understand it's correct, so I have marked the answer as valid.